# Correct way to include JWT token on HTTP packet (Cookie, header or JSON)

Tags: json, http, authentication, cookies, jwt

What is the standard and safest way to handle JWT tokens in HTTP packets?

Is it correct, that JWT shouldn't be set as cookie, as cookies make session hijacking trivial because browser includes it automatically, and thus doesn't serve any additional value to JWT token over plain session id cookie?

So, should the JWT token be included as a header or as a JSON attribute, or is this a matter of practice?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies and the Authorization header both have pros and cons.

Cookies allow you to prevent javascript from accessing the values, but if you only allow it in a Authorization header, you don't need any additional CSRF protection.

Cookies also allow you to easily protect non-javascript requests such as `<img` tags.

So there is no correct answer, and there is no standard. You need to figure out what's important to you.

Comment: What you mean by cookies preventing javascript from accessing the values and protecting from <img> tags? I thought cookies ARE vulnerable to javascript and CSRF based attacks. Does the authorization header falsify this premise? Also, I don't understand how storing token in cookie provides ANY additional security to just plain session id in a cookie, as browser would attach this cookie to request automatically. What makes a lot more sense to me, is that token is in the TLS encrypted header/body of server response and needs to be added in each request programmatically to avoid session riding.

Comment: @TuomasToivonen what I meant with 'cookies preventing javascript from accessing values' is 'HttpOnly' cookies. Look it up.

As for `<img>` tags. You basically can't automatically add authorization headers to those. Cookies will automatically be attached those requests as well, but an Authorization header will not. And yes Cookies _do_ allow CSRF requests if you don't have additional protection.

Comment: So overall cookies + csrf token approach seems more secure, as it protects from csrf and xss

Comment: @TuomasToivonen. I don't really like saying 'a is more secure than b' in cases like these, because it really depends on a lot of factors (including humans, choice of language, framework, etc). Main point is that both _can_ be secure depending on the situation.

Answer (score -1):

1. Use HTTPS
2. Set expire time of the token as small as possible(5 min, 30 min, nor months neither years).
3. Use refresh token to get a new token and update refresh token every time you update old token (and when user is logged in, no doubt)
4. Do not store passwords, credit card numbers and any confidential informations in the token ( I'm shure, you know it :) )
5. Store all necessary information for checking privileges ( or checking ip, for example ). It is good for REST API and horizontal scaling. And you need no cookies anymore ))
6. I send token via headers ( for example, curl -X GET -H "X-Access-Token:  ..." localhost:3000 )